# I can't use @ to locate files in Next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have been using @/. to locate and import files in Next JS and recently I deleted my node modules folder to reinstall all the packages to fix an issue.

However after that @/. has stopped working and I need to change all of them to ../

My jsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried clearing Next cache and reinstalling all the node packages but nothing worked!

Comment: Compiler Options is not enough to use absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

To use module aliases you need to configure both baseUrl and paths.
In `compilerOptions`, add `baseUrl` key and set it to `'.'` or `'src'` depending on your folder structure.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```